# Elevated transaminases after blood transfusion?

Tags: microbiology, homework, transfusion, hepatitis

This sparks HCV immediately in my mind.
However, there may be other possibilities too.

**What can you deduce from elevated transaminases if you only know that the healthy adult patient received blood transfusion in Africa?**